# mod_rewrite - need to match this code with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, drupal, mod-rewrite

I want to strip out the ?q= from my old drupal links for my site now in Wordpress

I need help with two things.

First, how do I specify a range of words instead of numbers, as in the snippet below? Once I do that will this code work to redirect ".../?q=postname" to simply ".../postname"?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule .* http://www.mysite.com/?q=%1 [R=301,L]
```

Secondly, once i have that code working, how do I integrate it with the default Wordpress mod_rewrite (which is below)?

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=(\w+)$
RewriteRule .* http://www.mysite.com/%1? [R=301,L]
```

BTW I would use [R=302,L] at first until I make sure everything works as expected. If you use 301 with wrong RewriteRule browser will cache the redirect and any further RewriteRule changes would require you to restart browser for each code change to see any difference.

Comment: Doesn't quite work - it redirects www.mysite.com/?q=postname to www.mysite.com/postname?q=postname and thus a 404

Comment: @ChrisBishop I updated rewrite rule so it doesn't pass query strings, but it will remove all query string variables not just "q".

Comment: That seems to work! Thank you very much, this is a huge help and prevents many old links from going dead.